# How to change the number of replicas in Galaxybase?

Tags: graph-databases

I'm using a graph database called Galaxybase. After using it for one month, I want to change the number of replicas due to some new needs. I restarted Galaxybase and reset the number of replicas in the popup window, but the changes were not applied after the startup completed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To modify the number of replicas, you need to restart the cluster, reset the value in the pop-up window.
After the startup is completed, **click the "Data Balancing" button** to rebalance the data. Once the data balancing is completed, the modification of the number of replicas is successful.